# Android Twitter Fabric - Persisting a Tweet

Tags: android, twitter

Using Android Twitter Fabric SDK to get a Tweet and show it inside of a TweetView or CompactTweetView.

I want to persist a Tweet and then recreate the same Tweet later without asking for the data from Twitter, which could cause an error if asked too many times.

I know I can get the tweet using

```
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.Tweet;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.tweetui.TweetUtils;


long mTweetId = //some number representing a tweet on Twitter

TweetUtils.loadTweet(mTweetId, this);  //the class implements LoadCallback<Tweet>

//if successful then this method is called
@Override
public void success(Tweet mTweet) 
{
    this.mTweet = mTweet; 

    //I now have the tweet, but I don't want to load it again in the future, instead I would
    //persist it to sharedPreferences or something and then recreate the Tweet calling
    //new Tweet(...) or something that will help me rebuilt the same Tweet which has already
    //been loaded 

}
```

I can even get some of the parameters of the tweet, but how to easily recreate the same tweet using data that has been persisted already.

Comment: how do you instantiate a `Tweet`? or does `Tweet` `implement Serializable`? Where is the javadoc or source code? If you had these things I could help :-)

Comment: since twitter fabric sdk for Android is so new the reference documentation for it is not available for Android on [https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android] , but it is available for Apple surprisingly.

Comment: Android docs for the Twitter Kit live at https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android

Answer (score 3):

We use GSON for serializing/deserializing Tweets in Fabric. It'd be a simple Process for you to use GSON too. Here is a snippet that creates a string as JSON which you could then save where you liked, and creating a Tweet from that string.

```
final Gson gson = new Gson();
final String tweetJson = gson.toJson(tweet);
final Tweet tweet = gson.fromJson(tweetJson, Tweet.class);
```

Comment: this looks promising. I have since moved on to a different project, but I will make some time to test this and get back to you soon! Once I confirm I will mark it as the accepted answer. THANKS.